# Installing Ubuntu Core on Intel NUC

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-core

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Core on my new Intel NUC i7.

I am following [this guide](https://ubuntu.com/download/intel-nuc) and have made it **step 7 - First boot setup.**

I get to the display where the prompt "Press enter to configure", except when I hit enter there are no options to begin configuring my network and I'm stuck. It just says "done" or "cancel".

What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty new to Linux and am not super technical. Any help is much appreciated!